# How can I duplicate an element in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have written a script to recurse over folders and wrap a `<td>` tag in a `<title>` tag. After some consideration, I'd prefer to keep the `<td>` and add in a new `<title>` tag in the head of the document, but I am not sure how to do this.

The code below will run to wrap the `<td>` tags in `<title>` tags, but how can I instead copy the text in this `<td>` into the `<head>` of my html document, surrounded by `<title>` tags.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def clean_up_folder(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for f in files:
                clean_up_file(os.path.join(root, f))

def clean_up_file(original_file):
    with open(original_file) as orig_f2:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f2.read())
    for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='title'):
        t.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('title'))
    with open(original_file, 'w') as orig_f:
        if soup.original_encoding is not None:
            orig_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))


clean_up_folder('Test')
```

Essentially I want to ctrl + c the text in my `<td class="title">` and ctrl + v it inside the `<head></head>` tag, encased in `<title></title>` tags. Is it possible to do this? Any pointers?

Comment: you can only have one `<title>` tag in the head of the document - do you have only one `<td class="title">` ?

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, only one '<td class='title>' in my documents. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, make a new `<title>` tag with the `.string` from your `<td class="title">` then `.append` the title tag to the `<head>`.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def clean_up_folder(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for f in files:
            clean_up_file(os.path.join(root, f))

def clean_up_file(original_file):
    with open(original_file) as orig_f2:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f2.read())

    title = soup.new_tag('title')
    td = soup.find('td', class_='title')
    if td is not None and td.string is not None:
        title.string = td.string

    head = soup.find('head')
    if head is not None:
        head.append(title)

    with open(original_file, 'w') as orig_f:
        if soup.original_encoding is not None:
            orig_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))


clean_up_folder('Test')
```

See docs:

- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string
- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append

Comment: thank you so much for this. When I try and run this code, it runs for a period and then encounters "TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances". I have tried to play around with it and not gotten too far - any idea what may be the cause of this? Thanks so much again, I didn't realise you could make tags like this :).

Comment: I'd need to see the whole error message to be any help

Comment: the error message is :    title.string = td.string
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 819, in string self.append(string.__class__(string))
TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances. Thanks again :)